# How can I reduce time taken for Cardano Triplet Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

> What is Cardano Triplet ?

If a set of any three positive integers, let's say `a`, `b` and `c` satisfies the condition

```
cbrt(a + b(sqrt(c)) + cbrt(a - b(sqrt(c)) == 1
```

Explanation.

if `sum of Cubic Root of a + (b * square root of c) and Cubic root of a - (b * square root of c) equals 1` then (a, b, c) is said to be a Cardano triplet.

cbrt represents Cubic Root and sqrt means Square Root.

A integer `n` will be given, so the numbers a, b and c that we take when added should be lesser than or equal to n.

In short `a + b + c <= n`.

Constraint : n <= 2^31 -1.

> Problem

I've already done something which finds out the correct triplets but when the value of n is greater than 1000 the program runs forever.

```
public static void cardanoTriplets(long n) {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

        long numberOfPairs = 0;

        for (long a = 0; a <= n; a++) {
            for (long b = 0; b <= n; b++) {
                for (long c = 0; c <= (n - a - b); c++) {
                    if ((a + b + c) == n) {
                        double val = b * Math.sqrt(c);
                        double LHS = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(Math.cbrt(a + val)));
                        double RHS = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(Math.cbrt(a - val)));
                        double addedVal = LHS + RHS;
                        //System.out.println("RHS and LHS -: ( " + RHS + " , " + LHS + " )");

                        if (addedVal == 1.0d) {
                            numberOfPairs++;
                            //System.out.println(a);
                            //System.out.println(b);
                            //System.out.println(c + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(numberOfPairs);
    }
```

> Results

- When I pass the value of **n as 8**, on average the time taken to find the cardano triplet is **31ms** and sometimes as low as **16ms**. The result was accurate and the result is just one and the triplet is (2, 1, 5).
- But when I pass the value of **n as 1000**, it increases to about **1015ms** and the result are not as accurate. It misses out almost 19 triplets. Total number of triplets are 149 for n == 1000.
- When the value of n > 1000, let's say **5000**, it took **29271ms** which is 29 seconds approx and the triplets found are 3364.

Is there any way to reduce time taken to a reasonable amount like less than 5 seconds ?

If so how ?

My Device Specs :

Processor : AMD Ryzen 5 3500U Quad Core

RAM : 8 GB

IDE used : IntelliJ IDEA v2021.2.3 (Community Edition)

Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you formatting the values?  Also, small thing: calculate `b * Math.sqrt(c)` once instead of twice per loop.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected it and did it again but still then it feels negligible amount of time is faster :(

Comment: Please post an updated version and also the expected result for your test data.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885095/parametrization-of-cardano-triplet

Comment: @josejuan I also came across this link but it says _That is really faster to compute for higher numbers than the previous form, but it goes up really fast and I need BigInteger (Java) that slows down again the code._ Also I did not figure out what is the benefit of `k`

Comment: @c0der A updated version and also the result and my expected result are also has been updated. :)

Comment: @c0der I'm formatting the decimal values because the results are more accurate when it is done in decimal form rather than as whole number.

Comment: What is the correct number of triplets for n = 5000 ?

Comment: I actually don't know :( , But I'm very sure that the accuracy is decreasing as the value of n is increasing.

Comment: your implementation assumptions differs from your own question for condition `a+b+c==n`. your question says `<=n`....

Answer (score 5):

This is a number-theoretical problem; using an imprecise floating point is obviously wrong.

The correct solution requires some math insight. Cardano's name is a great hint.

The expression

```
cbrt(a + b(sqrt(c)) + cbrt(a - b(sqrt(c))
```

describes [a root of a certain cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula). Specifically, the roots of an equation

```
x^3 + px - q = 0
```

are

```
cbrt(q/2 + sqrt((q/2)^2 + (p/3)^3)) + cbrt(q/2) - sqrt(q/2)^2 + (p/3)^3))
```

Comparing with your problem statement, conclude that `a = q/2`, and `c*b^2 = (q/2)^2 + (p/3)^3`

Since `a` is an integer, `q` must be even, and since `b, c` are also integers, `p` must be divisible by `3`. Therefore we are interested in the equations

```
x^3 + 3ux - 2a = 0
```

having `1` as a root. That narrows the problem down to searching `u, v` such that `1 + 3u - 2a = 0`. Here `u^3 + a^2 = b^2*c`. Notice that `u` must be odd.

All these observations lead to a (pseudo)code:

```
   for u in range(1, n, 2)
       a = (1 + 3u)/2
       t = u^3 + a^2
       find the largest b such that b^2 divides t
       c = t / b^2
       if a + b + c < n
           they are a Cardano triplet
```

Comment: I implemented this solution in c#. it took 170ms in release mode when n=1000. Excellent on the math! I made a little change on:  find the largest b such that b^2 divides t. I changed it to: find all b where b^2 divides t. I could edit the answer but first want to know if you are ok me doing so.

Comment: @Aldert In the spirit of the number theory we usually assume that $c$ is square-free. If the problem does not have such a restriction, so be it. I would rather keep the original wording.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem, is the loop-in-loop-in-loop what will take 1.000.000.000 rounds for n=1000.

As you know already that n = a + b + c, you can take one loop out. the c-loop
and rewrite as:

```
for (long a = 0; a <= n; a++) {
            for (long b = 0; b <= (n - a); b++) {
                long c = n - a - b;
```

so you go from n * n * n -> n * n

If the equation is  n => a + b + c (as in your problem statement), you can use:

```
for (long a = 0; a <= n; a++) {
        for (long b = 0; b <= (n - a); b++) {
            for (long c = 0; c <= (n - a - b); c++) {
```

Second, you are doing a format to a decimal and then convert back to double where as the Math.cbrt gives already a double. I would suggest not doing so.

The problem of "missing 19 triplets" is related to the point above. You only accept 1.0d as the correct answer, there in the previous step you did formatting on the doubles (most likely giving rounding issues). Even if you would take out the formatting, I believe it is better to allow for a bit more rounding error..

something like:

```
if (0.999 < addedVal && addedVal <  1.001)
```

However, I have no idea on the math of this equation as there must be a reason why you say there are 149 triplets.. Depending on the rounding for sure you have different answers... I believe there is something like mathemathical proof the triplets are 1.

Last what you can do: I believe the calculation of the Math.cbrt is not that fast. You are repeating this a lot. You can keep track of your calculation by placing the result of the Math,cbrt in a HashSet. The Key is the input and the Value the result of the Math.cbrt.

So first check if you have the Key already in the HashSet, if not calculate the cbrt and place it, if already available us it..

Comment: problem is that what he has done differs from his own problem. In his implementation, he has a condition `((a + b + c) == n)` which in this case we can use your equation and removing 1 loop completely. But in the question he says `a + b + c <= n` which conflicts with his implementation. if this condition is correct, we cannot remove the 3rd loops simply.

Comment: You are right, I was looking at the code only when I mad ethe answer. Viknesh what is correct?

Comment: @Aldert They way you mentioned was not accurate but still it was able to reduce time to a large numbers. It went from 1500ms to 1015ms but the result was still same and the the approach to 1.0d is not working as it decreases the accuracy.

Comment: Where you able to implement the math answer? This is the proof I was looking for but I do not fully understand it yet...

Comment: You're asking where do I found this question and where I'm checking the answers right ? If so then , I found this question on HackerRank the link : https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler251/problem?isFullScreen=true